# Redirect standard output to a file + ANT + No output on console

Tags: java, ant

I'd like to redirect my standard output that gets printed in command prompt to be printed in a file instead of the console. 
I used the [Recorder task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html). And it partially answers my question.
It does help print the output to the file but I can't prevent the output from being printed on the command prompt as well.

Most questions have been answered with the recorder task itself but nothing specific for my query.

**Question:**

Is there any way in which I can only have the output printing take place in the file and **NOT** on my console?

Comment: Why not just redirect it to `/dev/null` in the command line?

Comment: @CAustin I do not want the user to redirect the output to any location. Specifying /dev/null on the console still has the possibility of the user not entering it in the console in which case the output will be printed on the terminal.
This "no output on console" must be all done from within the ant build script.

Comment: There is nothing that you can put in your Ant script that would do this. You would have to edit the the code and create a custom Ant jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by running ant script like this(Assumed you running in Windows)

`ant <targetname> >\path\to\out\file.txt`

This command redirects everything to test file.